# Display name in place of title in search result

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results

I would like to know if there is a way to display the "Name" of the document in place of the title in the search result panel?

I am using Search Core Results Web Part.

I saw a post to modify xslt in result query option but there is no suitable field to display the Name.

Comment: which version of sharepoint you have 2010 or 2013?

Comment: I'm using sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Edit Page
2. Edit Search Core Result Properties
3. Display Properties -> Uncheck "Use Location Visualization"
4. Click on button "XSL Editor..."
5. In the new window search for

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
   ```
6. Replace that with

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
   ```

Comment: thanks for your proposition but how to edit OSSSearchResults.aspx?

Comment: I would say you create a separate page. Then add Search Core Result Webpart and use that. You also need to modify your Search Box property so that it will send the results to the new page you are going to create

Comment: when i open xsl editor, it's empty